# My fanpage comes first in the google than my Blog

Tags: seo, blogs, facebook-page

I'm new here and 
This is the first question of mine on Stackoverflow.

Well, my question is regarding the Blog that I have... Now I'm not gonna spam here by providing my link and well, I have a blog and also a fanpage for that on Facebook. If I type my blog's name on google, my blog used to come on top of all the search results, infact I wish that. 
I've created a fan-page for my blog 2 days ago and now it has around 350 likes. Now, if I search for my blog name on google, Facebook Fanpage comes on the top and 2nd result is my blog!!
How to make my Blog beat my fan-page?? Yeah, my blog has pretty good quality back-links and also it is linked with the facebook and twitter pages..
How to bring back my blog to the top again??
And also, My blog has a Twitter page and it has around 180 followers but it is not showing up at all in the Google search..
How to make it appear?? (Ofcourse Twitter is a High PR site but not showing up like Facebook Page).

Thank You!!!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO and how to improve their search engine ranking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your blog back up above the Facebook page you would have to increase Google's trust in your domain. So that would mean posting fresh new relevent content regularly. Getting more backlinks. Not just to the homepage, but also to individual articles as well.

These backlinks also need to come from a diverse range of quality domains.

You are definitely not the only one with this kind of problem. There are numerous people who have an e-commerce website who also sell their product on Amazon.com. Their Amazon.com listing usually outranks their own website and therefor they are losing money.

Outranking a domain like Facebook or Amazon is possible but you won't see results overnight.

Comment: Haha... Amazing explanation. My domain is Blogger (Mine is not commercial, but a free tutorial one though).. Thank you so much for your answer.. I will follow your instructions.. But I can't figure out why Twitter page is not showing up in that case...

Comment: Thank you)

Twitter often ranks a lot below Facebook profiles. So that's not so weird :)

Could you mark my question as the right answer if your answer is answered? Otherwise i would love to answer anything i might have forgotten.